# Cannot install heroku's plugin

Tags: java, heroku, war, heroku-postgres

Hello I want to deploy my Java web app to heroku but it doesnt go well at all. 
I need to execute this command to deploy war file :

```
heroku deploy:war --war build/libs/GradleSample.war --app
```

however, when i do it, i get this message : deploy:war is not a heroku command.

So I need to run this command:

> heroku plugins:install https://github.com/heroku/heroku-deploy

But I get this error messages;

> ▸    npm ERR! node v6.9.5
>    ▸    npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
>    ▸    npm ERR! code EISDIR
>    ▸    npm ERR! errno -21
>    ▸    npm ERR! syscall read
>    ▸
>    ▸    npm ERR! eisdir EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
>    ▸    npm ERR! eisdir This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
>    ▸    npm ERR! eisdir and is related to npm not being able to find a package.json in
>    ▸    npm ERR! eisdir a package you are trying to install.
>    ▸
>    ▸    npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>    ▸    npm ERR!     /Users/.local/share/heroku/plugins/npm-debug.log
>    ▸
>    ▸    Try running again with HEROKU_DEBUG=1 to see more output.

What should i do to fix this? I really want to deploy my app on heroku. I need your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run this command:

```
heroku plugins:install heroku-cli-deploy
```

Then run:

```
heroku deploy:war build/libs/GradleSample.war
```

The https://github.com/heroku/heroku-deploy repo is deprecated (as mentioned in the [README](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-deploy/blob/master/README.md))

Comment: Thank you so much! You are such a kind person!